# React setInterval Timer Lags When on Separate Browser Tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, web-worker

I have a basic timer in React that implements `setInterval()`. I've read that this can be a bit problematic with lag and I have found it to be so- whenever I go to a different tab on Chrome for a prolongued period of time, it definitely starts to lag. I would like to implement a basic web worker in JavaScript to improve my timer, but not sure how to do it. Here is how my clock is powered:

```
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);  
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
  const countRef = useRef(null);
  const [minutes,setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds,setSeconds]= useState(0);

  const timeCeiling = 7800; //clock goes up to 130 minutes
  const timeFloor = 60;

  useEffect(() => {
    setMinutes(Math.floor(timer / 60));
    setSeconds(timer % 60);
  }, [timer]);

  //Start Timer
  const handleStart = () => {
    countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  //Pause Timer
  const handlePause = () => {
    clearInterval(countRef.current);
    setIsPaused(false);
  };

  //Resume Timer
  const handleResume = () => {
    setIsPaused(true);
    countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  //Reset Timer
  const handleReset = () => {
    clearInterval(countRef.current);
    setIsActive(false);
    setIsPaused(false);
    setTimer(0)
  };

  //And now here are the functions to increment and decrement minutes and seconds: 
  const increaseMinutes = () => {
    timer >= timeCeiling ? checkMaximumTime() : setTimer((timer) => timer + 60);
  };

  const decreaseMinutes = () => {
    timer < timeFloor ? checkMinimumTime() : setTimer((timer) => timer - 60);
  };

  const increaseSeconds = () => {
    setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
  };

  const decreaseSeconds = () => {
    timer === 0 ? checkMinimumTime() : setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);
  };

  const checkMinimumTime = () => {
    alert("Can't go lower than zero minutes!");
    return;
  };

  const checkMaximumTime = () => {
    alert("Maximum minutes reached");
    return;
  };
```

All the functions implement `onClick` buttons in the JSX. I wanted to know how I can implement web workers to eliminate the lag when browsing other tabs, or any other solution.

Comment: No, don't implement a web worker! The overhead would be so unimaginably high that it would only be more likely to be throttled when in the background.